# C++ Change access of built-in function, i.e. Smart Pointer get()

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

How can I change public function access of built-in libraries. For example:

I'm using `const std::unique_ptr&`. I don't want anyone to use function `.get()` to get raw pointer, because you can't suspend anyone to use `delete` raw pointer, because after deallocation of `unique_ptr` there gonna be runtime error that giving error about `delete`

With `const reference` I prevent user from using `std::move()`. I want to prevent user from using `.get()` too. How can I do it?

```
void SmartPointerUsage(const std::unique_ptr<A>& ref)
{
    A* rawPtr = ref.get();     // No compiler error, I want to prevent using that function
    std::unique_ptr<A> moved = std::move(ref); // Gives compiler error, that's what I need
}
```

Edit 1: Actually, deleting operator `delete` gives me compiler error, not runtime, when using smart pointers

Comment: you cannot prevent users to do wrong things with absolute certainty. You can try but it will be annoying for lot of users and those that really want can still use it wrong. Would you also prevent the user to get a reference to the object because it can be dangling? Then you cannot let the user access anything

Comment: `cost auto& ref = *the_unique_ptr;` there you go. There is no way you can prevent this reference being accessible to the user and dangling when the smart pointer destroyed the object unless you give the user no access at all

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That's a pit. Okay. Do you think it's a good design to use `unique_ptr` like this? I guess using just raw pointer of manageable `unique_ptr` object is not that good.

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? Why do you want to pass a smart pointer in the first place? Smart pointers are to manage ownership, but it seems that this is just what you want to prevent. Why is the parameter not a `const A&` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Oh, wait a bit. YOU RIGHT! I should use `const A&`. OMG, thanks a lot!

Comment: what i said, if the parameter is  `const A&` then you can still get the address of that object store it somewhere and potentially use it even after the actual object is long gone. C++ is not designed to be a safe or foolproof language. You do not need a smart pointer to do wrong things